# Non-stoichometric compounds

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, covalent-compounds

I am looking for references (review articles, reports) about non-stoichometric compounds. Any idea of where should I look?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-stoichiometric_compound

Comment: Wikipedia articles are "light", I am searching for something more "hard" and professional.

Comment: The Wikipedia article at least links to some book references. Maybe that's useful...

Answer (score 3):

There are several resources available for this, for example, searching in [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com) yields over 37,000 articles (this is without any filters for age or specifics).

Organisations such as the American Chemical Society have a searchable [publications link](http://www.acs.org/content/acs/en/publications.html); related, CAS has a [searchable reference list](http://www.cas.org/content/references) and [ChemWorx](https://pc.acschemworx.acs.org/platinum/LoginPage.jsp?home=chemworx&code=1000#home) which is a way to manage your research.  A similar set up is available with the [Royal Society of Chemistry](http://www.rsc.org/publishing/currentawareness/).

Individual universities also have searches/tutorials - for example, The University of California, Davis have a ['ChemWiki'](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Quantum_Mechanics/Atomic_Theory/Chemical_Compounds/Case_Study%3a_Non-Stoichometric_Bonding_in_Materials).  Additionally, university libraries also are often accessible to the public and have search functions for journal articles, books.  Some universities, such as the University of Connecticut have [Research Database Locator](http://rdl.lib.uconn.edu/subjects/1878).

As mentioned in the comments, Wikipedia, particularly if a page is written well, have several links to journal articles and books etc.